# Fullcalendar custom number of days

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I use fullcalendar

But I want a 2 day view. Is there a possibility for that?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something like this to display a 2-day conference schedule, and effected it by doing the following:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        slotMinutes: 15,
        year: 2014,
        month: 1,
        date: 13,
        minTime: 8,
        maxTime: 21,
        hiddenDays: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
        firstDay: 1,
        editable: false,
        height: 800,
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: '',
            right: ''
        },
        events: eventsArray
    });
```

Effectively I set the start date of the conference using **year/month/date**, (and for my locale set Monday to be the first day of the Week so Sunday appeared on the right, using **firstDay**) then hid the other days of the week using **hiddenDays**. I also hid the header, so people couldn't browse next/prev/etc.

Comment: I will use this until i find a final solution more dynamically